# in HTML I can't get the CSS changes to appear on the web page

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code

I have this HTML code on Microsoft Visual Studio Code:
In CSS I try to call **section**, **home-content h3**, **home-content h1**, **home-content p**, **social-media a** like this:

```css
section {
  min-height: 100vh;
  padding: 10rem 95 2rem;
}

.home-content h3 {
  font-size: 3.2rem;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.home-content h1 {
  font-size: 5.6rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 1.3;
}

.home-content p {
  font-size: 1.6rem;
}

.social-media a {
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 4rem;
  height: 4rem;
  background: transparent;
  border: .2rem solid var(--main-color);
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: var(--main-color);
  margin: 3rem 1.5rem 3rem 0;
}
```

```html
<section class="home" id="home">
  <div class="home-content">
    <h3>Hello, It's Me</h3>
    <h1>Simone Marino</h1>
    <h3> And I'm a <span> Data Analyst</span></h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eos veritatis obcaecati consequatur eveniet id illo optio placeat nemo aspernatur magnam? Sunt velit nihil impedit quisquam accusantium aspernatur est explicabo. Vitae!</p>
    <div class="social-media">
      <a href="#"><i class='bx bxl-facebook' ></i></a>
      <a href="#"><i class='bx bxl-twitter' ></i></a>
      <a href="#"><i class='bx bxl-instagram-alt' ></i></a>
      <a href="#"><i class='bx bxl-linkedin' ></i></a>
    </div>
    <a href="#" class="btn"> Download CV</a>
  </div>
```

but no change occurs on the web page.

The HTML and CSS code were created and saved in separate files with the appropriate extensions.

What can I do to fix this?

I have tried putting and removing the "." before the code but no change happens.

Comment: I'm going to assume the missing **</section>** happened copying and pasting here?

Comment: Also look at your console, and make sure your CSS file is actually loading into the page .. My guess is the CSS file is a 404.  Based on the fact that in the code snip, it works just fine.

Comment: the closing tag is there </section>, I missed it in pasting the code on stack overflow. CSS file works, because I am on the web page of implemented functions. The problem is always occurring on <section>